# Block msiexec or psexec from installing software to my computer via remote

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-installer

How to block/prevent msiexec or psexec from installing software to my computer remotely without:

- changing the "admin" password
- disconnecting from the network
- disabling file sharing

Comment: Setup your firewall to disallow the corresponding remote connections.

Comment: @Seth can you be more specific?

Comment: [psexec Couldn't access \\IP/computername The system cannot find the path specified](https://serverfault.com/questions/227732/psexec-couldnt-access-ip-computername-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specifi), SMB is also used for filesharing etc. so you will have to think about what you want to do with your machine. The Windows firewall should be sufficient to block that communication.

Comment: @Seth i don't want to block SMB, is there any other option?